# Ubuntu 12.04, why service procps start doesn't start procps?

Tags: 12.04, boot, configuration, upstart

I have been trying to get some settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to take effect upon rebooting.  So, I did the following as the `root` user on this node running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit

```
# service procps status
procps stop/waiting
# service procps start
procps stop/waiting
```

No matter how I tried. The `/etc/init/procps` is stock as shown below. I have not touched it (not familiar with upstart yet).

```
# procps - set sysctls from /etc/sysctl.conf
#
# This task sets kernel sysctl variables from /etc/sysctl.conf and
# /etc/sysctl.d

description     "set sysctls from /etc/sysctl.conf"

instance $UPSTART_EVENTS
env UPSTART_EVENTS=

start on virtual-filesystems or static-network-up

task
script
    cat /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf /etc/sysctl.conf | sysctl -e -p -
end script
```

I would appreciate it very much for any hints about how to start this `upstart` job.

Up to now, I always have to manually issue `/sbin/sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`. It gets old really fast...

Thanks,

-- Zack

Answer (score 5):

The procps service really isn't a long-running daemon. `service procps start` just invokes the script in `/etc/init/procps`, which causes all the contents of `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.conf` to be piped to `sysctl -e -p -`.

So, the act of running `service procps start` is pretty much the same as what you are manually doing, and should already be applying at boot, assuming your procps upstart job is configured to run.

Comment: Just one correction (typo?): if the script "/etc/init/procps" doesn't work, try to use "/etc/init.d/procps" instead.