# Strange sysctl behavior on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: 16.04, server, 18.04

Let's say I have an Ubuntu bionic server that I wish to disable IPv6 on. (Important: This is not an XY Problem, please don't guess at what I'm trying to achieve or ask me why I want to do this. I know how great and wonderful IPv6 is, no need to preach to the choir.) One way to do this is to set the following sysctls:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

When `sysctl` is run manually with the settings above, this disables all IPv6 networking on the host:

```
# ip -6 a
#
```

Great, but that doesn't persist through a reboot. The recommended way to make sysctls persist is to put them in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, or a file in `/etc/sysctl.d`. I did that, but after a reboot, IPv6 is still there:

```
# ip -6 addr
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 <censored>/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591985sec preferred_lft 604785sec
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feae:c158/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And yet, the sysctls appear to be correctly set:

```
# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

However when I set them on the command line, to the same value, suddenly IPv6 is *actually* disabled:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1 net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
# ip -6 addr
#
```

So my question, then, is: Why does setting sysctls to specific non-default values in `/etc/sysctl.d/` *appear* to be doing something according to the output of `sysctl` itself, and yet *not* actually affecting the kernel's behavior? Is there some subtle difference between setting a sysctl and having it take effect?

I know that `sysctl` is an interface for `/proc/sys` but I am seeing the same thing there as well:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 
1
# ip -6 a
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 <censored>/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591945sec preferred_lft 604745sec
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feae:c158/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
# ip -6 a
#
```

Also, I have done significant research into this, this question is NOT a dupe of any of these:

- [How to disable IPv6 permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309461/how-to-disable-ipv6-permanently?rq=1)
- [Disable IPv6 on Ubuntu 17.10 (Netplan)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988709/disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu-17-10-netplan?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [/etc/sysctl.conf doesn't persist after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443032/etc-sysctl-conf-doesnt-persist-after-reboot)
- [/etc/sysctl.conf settings do not last after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053997/etc-sysctl-conf-settings-do-not-last-after-reboot?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Ubuntu 12.04, why service procps start doesn't start procps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209952/ubuntu-12-04-why-service-procps-start-doesnt-start-procps?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Possibly related to this? [Some sysctls are ignored on boot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/50093)

Answer (score 0):

I made a realy bad hack to solve this Problem on bionic. It is a timing problem, as steeldriver mentiond.

```
cp -a /lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysctl.service /etc/systemd/system/
```

In the new File I add `Requires=network.target`

create a file `etc/sysctl.d/50-ipv6.conf` with content `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1` If you use NetworkManager on your server don't forget to set method=ignore

```
[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=ignore
```

in your network connection.

I hope I wrote understandable.